# Not able to get New-F5Item cmdlet

Tags: powershell, f5

I am creating a pool in F5.
i came across the below link which gives a function of creating a Pool.

(https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/f5-ltm/1.4.154/Content/Public%5CNew-Pool.ps1)

All the things are fine. i have installed F5-LTM module for powershell also.

```
Install-Module -Name F5-LTM -RequiredVersion 1.4.280
```

I am not able to see the **"New-F5Item"** cmdlts.

Can you please let me know about this cmdlet.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the file list in PSGallery, you'll notice that the package contains the script file `Private\New-F5Item.ps1`, indicating that `New-F5Item` is probably not exported by the module.

When a command is not exported, it can only be discovered/called from other functions in the same module - which is why you don't see it when doing `Get-Command` or similar.